# Magento product page missing code for product and footer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I just moved my magento site to a new server and have hit a snag on product pages.
Magento doesnt render any code after this (this is the last ten lines of html it delivers)

```
        ....
        <h2>Quick Overview</h2>
        <div class="std">Add an extra hour of shooting time</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-img-box">
<p class="product-image">
```

I have cleared all caches and rebuilt indexes. I have also checked the error logs and nothing shows on the error log (I do have display errors turned on E_ALL). I have set my memory limit to 4096mb.

Has anyone see this before? I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you changed the DB credentials?

Comment: Does the home page work?

Comment: home page works but also cuts off at the bottom. db and admin work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your page die just before loading catalog image:

Do you have GD (or all the other) php extension install?

See [Required PHP Extensions for Magento eCommerce](http://www.activoinc.com/blog/2009/08/27/required-php-extensions-for-magento-ecommerce/)

Also it could be the wrong permission on you catalog images. See [Magento Filesystem Permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions)

Comment: I installed gd and the other extensions and cleared the caches, but it didn't make a difference. Permissions are ok too.

Comment: Are you looking for error in your server error_log or on page display? Try installing a fresh copy of magento (backup your current magento files and use a different db name) when you get it to work they you could just rsync the backup copy over your fresh install

Comment: This did fix it after all. I forgot to add the call to php.ini to use the .so.